# NSArray to NSMutableArray to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am using the NetworkExtension Framework (I do have proper entitlements and everything works fine). 
However, I am trying to access the properties, and did not discover any direct means through the documentation on developer.apple.com. There were properties listed, but no means of accessing them. 
1. SSID (NSString)
2. BSSID (NSString)
3. Signal Strength (Double)

I did not see anything in terms of accessing these properties directly, so I decided to get an array of supported interfaces. 
In my case, I am using Objective-C with NSArray Supported interfaces.

I obtain the array of supported interfaces (current one is the first one). Here is the code that I use to obtain that array.

```
 NSArray *networkInterfaces = [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces];
```

I get this result (I altered the outcome slightly to hide sensitive information:

```
2016-04-22 14:37:42.263 FlightPath[589:184926] (
"<CNNetwork SSID WiFiNetwork BSSID 00:a0:00:0a:00:0a [protected] [signal 0.884383] [Auto-Join] 0x12f655170>"
```

)

I am able to log this, and set it to a label/text view. However, I want to use the ObjectAtIndex property so I can populate say a SSID.text (label) with the objectFromIndex.

I have tried numerous of ways to convert the NSArray to a MutableArray, then to a NSString but couldn't get anywhere. Any thoughts, ideas?

Comment: A NSMutableArray is simply a *mutable* (modifiable) version of NSArray.  It sounds like what you really want to do is parse a field out of one of the entries in your array?

Comment: Pretty much spot on. I did convert the NSArray to an NSMutableArray using:  `NSMutableArray *mutableCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:networkInterfaces];`

Comment: @NathanDenlinger not directly related to your question, but for future reference, you can also create a mutable copy of any `NSObject` that implements the `NSMutableCopying` protocol using `NSMutableArray *mutableCopy = [networkInterfaces mutableCopy]`.  And, conversely, you can convert the mutable copy back to an immutable one using `[mutableCopy copy]`

Comment: @fullofsquirrels thank you very much!! I'll be sure to use that method next time! Always good to get a wide perspective on what I can do with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a mutable array. `[NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces]` returns an array of `NEHotspotNetwork` objects. That class in turn has properties to get the `SSID`, `BSSID`, and `signalStrength`.

```
NSArray *networkInterfaces = [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces];
NEHotspotNetwork *firstNetwork = [networkInterfaces firstObject];
NSString *ssid = firstNetwork.SSID;
NSString *bssid = firstNetwork.BSSID;
double signalStrength = firstNetwork.signalStrength;
```

Comment: Wow, I feel incredibly stupid about this. Well, thank you for pointing out my mistake. I appreciate very much what you inputted here. I was making that far far more complicated than needed.